# JQuery code iterating only through the last row of table and pushing it into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is my HTML Code:

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  var count = $("#treatmentTbl tr").length + 1;
  var medicalCondition = $("#medicalCondition").val();
  var medicalStatus = $("#medicalStatus").val();

  if (medicalCondition != "") {
    if (medicalStatus == "Treated") {
      $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id=" + count + "><td data-name=" + medicalCondition + ">" + medicalCondition + "</td><td><span class='label label-success' data-name=" + medicalStatus + ">" + medicalStatus + "</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
    } else {
      $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id=" + count + "><td data-name=" + medicalCondition + ">" + medicalCondition + "</td><td><span class='label label-danger' data-name=" + medicalStatus + ">" + medicalStatus + "</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
    }

    $("#medicalCondition").val('');
    $("#medicalStatus").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  }
});

$("button#btnpatientPastHistory").click(function() {
  var items = [],
    options = {};

  //Iterate all td's in second column
  $('table#medicalCondition tbody#treatmentTbl tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
    // table#medicalCondition tbody#treatmentTbl tr td:nth-child(2)
    options.medicalCondition = $(this).data("name");
    options.medicalStatus = $(this).next("td:nth-child(2)").data("name");
    // items.push("medicalCondition: "+$(this).data("name")+", medicalStatus: "+$(this).next("td:nth-child(2)").data("name"));
    items.push(options);
  });

  console.log(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onSubmit="return false;" id="patientPastHistory">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
            Past History
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" id="medicalCondition" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="Medical Condition">
                      <label for="medicalCondition">E.g. Asthama, Arthiritis, etc.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select class="form-control" id="medicalStatus">
                                            <option selected disabled value="">Select Treatment Status</option>
                                            <option value="Treated">Treated</option>
                                            <option value="Ongoing">Ongoing Treatment</option>
                                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <a id="btnAdd" class="btn green-meadow mt-repeater-btn-inline btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <table id="medicalCondition" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="60%"> Medical Condition </th>
                    <th width="30%"> Status </th>
                    <th width="10%"> Action </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="treatmentTbl">
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            {{-- Submit Button --}}
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2  mt-35">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                <button id="btnpatientPastHistory" class="fwb btn btn-circle green-meadow">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Changes</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                <button id="cancel" type="button" class="fwb btn btn-circle btn-outline dark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

what I am trying to do is I am trying to get data from the tr and then store it in an object then I am pushing it into an array unless all the tr data elements row is traversed. But what's happening with this code is that when I am doing console.log() it is taking the last data and then running each loop to store that data in objects again and again why so? can anyone help me with this

Comment: Because you're pushing _the same_ object again and again ... put `var options = {}` _inside_ the each loop, not before.

Comment: like this => `items.push({options})` ?

Comment: I agree this seems to be an inefficiency, but it's not the root problem...

Comment: Then where should and how should i add the code @CalebBertrand ?

Comment: No ... `var items = [], options = {};` - remove `, options = {}` here, and put `var options = {}` at the top of your loop callback function.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe that worked superperfect :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're overwriting the properties of a single object. You're not appending a new object each time you iterate in the loop. Also note that you can make the logic more succinct by using `map()` instead of `each()`. Try this:

```
$("button#btnpatientPastHistory").click(function() {
  var items = $('table#medicalCondition tbody#treatmentTbl tr td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
    return {
      medicalCondition: $(this).data("name"),
      medicalStatus: $(this).next("td:nth-child(2)").data("name")
    }
  }).get();

  console.log(items);
});
```

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  var count = $("#treatmentTbl tr").length + 1;
  var medicalCondition = $("#medicalCondition").val();
  var medicalStatus = $("#medicalStatus").val();

  if (medicalCondition != "") {
    if (medicalStatus == "Treated") {
      $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id=" + count + "><td data-name=" + medicalCondition + ">" + medicalCondition + "</td><td><span class='label label-success' data-name=" + medicalStatus + ">" + medicalStatus + "</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
    } else {
      $('#treatmentTbl').append("<tr style='text-transform: capitalize;' class='treatmentRow' data-id=" + count + "><td data-name=" + medicalCondition + ">" + medicalCondition + "</td><td><span class='label label-danger' data-name=" + medicalStatus + ">" + medicalStatus + "</span></td><td><a class='delBtn btn-circle btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a></td></tr>");
    }

    $("#medicalCondition").val('');
    $("#medicalStatus").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  }
});

$("button#btnpatientPastHistory").click(function() {
  var items = $('table#medicalCondition tbody#treatmentTbl tr td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
    return {
      medicalCondition: $(this).data("name"),
      medicalStatus: $(this).next("td:nth-child(2)").data("name")
    }
  }).get();

  console.log(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onSubmit="return false;" id="patientPastHistory">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <div class="portlet box blue-hoki">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
            Past History
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" id="medicalCondition" class="form-control typeahead-findings circle-input" style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="Medical Condition">
                      <label for="medicalCondition">E.g. Asthama, Arthiritis, etc.</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select class="form-control" id="medicalStatus">
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select Treatment Status</option>
                    <option value="Treated">Treated</option>
                    <option value="Ongoing">Ongoing Treatment</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                  <a id="btnAdd" class="btn green-meadow mt-repeater-btn-inline btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus">+</i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <table id="medicalCondition" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="60%"> Medical Condition </th>
                    <th width="30%"> Status </th>
                    <th width="10%"> Action </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="treatmentTbl">
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            {{-- Submit Button --}}
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2  mt-35">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                <button id="btnpatientPastHistory" class="fwb btn btn-circle green-meadow">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save Changes</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 nopad">
                <button id="cancel" type="button" class="fwb btn btn-circle btn-outline dark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```